# Excel macro - adding a word to a currency field

Tags: layout, excel, cell, vba

I've successfully copied a currency value to a field. Now I need to add a word, but this always makes me lose my currency format. Is there a way to solve this?

Example

```
Range("A2").Value = Range("A1") & "/link"
"Output"
A1 = € 2.800,00
A2 = 2800/link
"Wanted output"
A2 = € 2.800,00/link
```

I know I can record a macro and copy that, but that's only applicable for that certain case. The number is variable.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Range("A2").Value = Range("A1").Text & "/link"
```